# How does zookeeper internally achieve data consistency among leader and follower when leader fail

Tags: locking, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system

[Apache Zookeeper documentation](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.1.2/recipes.html#sc_recipes_Locks) described steps about how to implement a distributed lock, steps are:

1. Call `create()` with the sequence and ephemeral flags set.
2. Call `getChildren()`, check if the data created in step 1 has the "lowest sequence number"
3. ...

My question is: if leader A failed after step 1's `create()` (let's say, the sequence number it produced is `0001`), Zookeeper must have failover logic to elect another new leader B, but how does Zookeeper make sure later the `create()` happened in new leader B will issue the correct sequence (which should be `0002`)? otherwise it'll violate the exclusive lock property if if new leader B still produce the old sequence number `0001`.

Does Zookeeper achieve this by making sure write (from the previous leader A) will replicated to a quorums of nodes **before it replied to client** that the write operation is success? If this is the case, how to make sure the failover process will choose a follower that has the latest update to previous leader A?